# Oracle PL/SQL, how to debug a complex stored proc?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In the Oracle PL/SQL, how to debug a complex stored proc ?

for example, the codes below, it is using loop + correlated subquery. how to fully understand it ? I have learned that the best way to debug is divide-and-conquer, then how to cut this coding into small pieces  ?

Thanks

```
v_count := 1;

while v_count > 0
LOOP

update tbl_A a
set a.name = (select b.name from tbl_B b where a.id = b.id)
where a.id = (
    select c.id from tbl_C c where c.id = a.id
)

v_count := sql%rowcount;
END LOOP
```

Comment: This either does 1 update without affecting rows or goes into an infinite loop. And if this is just general dummy code, then the general advice is to never put SQL statements inside a procedural loop. SQL is a set based language and can do whatever you want in a single statement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what tools you're using, but if you get Oracle SQL Developer, it includes a debugger that allows you to step through the code line by line, set breakpoints, and so forth - all the typical features of a debugging GUI.

And, it's free. [Get it here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting out part of the code, then store the so-far result in a variable.
Then you can just select it like: `SELECT @varname` At least that's how MYSQL 5.x handles it.